# Websockets — Invalid UTF-8 bytes

Tags: python, utf-8, websocket, ws4py

I'm trying to build a simple echoing server with Websockets, but I can only get the connection to stay alive for a few seconds before I get an error. The reason I'm getting for the websocket closing is "Invalid UTF-8 bytes", but I'm not sure where those invalid bytes are coming from. Here is my websocket client:

```
// websocket-client.es6
this.ws = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:8080/websocket-test/ws`);
this.ws.onopen = (event) => {
  this.ws.send('opening');
  setInterval(() => {
    this.ws.send('heartbeat');
  }, 5000);
};
this.ws.onmessage = (event) => {
  console.log(event);
};
this.ws.onclose = (event) => {
  console.log('websocket closing: %O', event);
};
this.ws.onerror = (event) => {
  console.error('error: %O', event);
}
```

My server is Cherrypy with ws4py:

```
# websocket-server.py
class MyWebSocket(WebSocket):
    def received_message(self, message):
        cherrypy.log('received %s' % message)
        self.send(message.data, message.is_binary)

    def closed(self, code, reason=None):
        cherrypy.log('closed. code %s, reason: %s' % (code, reason))
```

When I run the app, this is what I get on the server side:

```
[10/Feb/2016:16:39:42]  received opening
[10/Feb/2016:16:39:47]  received --heartbeat--
[10/Feb/2016:16:39:52]  received --heartbeat--
[10/Feb/2016:16:39:57]  received --heartbeat--
[10/Feb/2016:16:40:02]  received --heartbeat--
[10/Feb/2016:16:40:07]  received --heartbeat--
[10/Feb/2016:16:40:12]  received --heartbeat--
[10/Feb/2016:16:40:17]  received -heLrtbHat-5
[10/Feb/2016:16:40:22]  received -heLrtbHat-
```

The last two messages also have an open rectangle after the second dash.

and this is what Chrome Dev Tools console says:

```
MessageEvent { data: "opening", type: "message" }
websocket closed: CloseEvent { code: 1007, reason: "Invalid UTF-8 bytes", type: "close" }
```

Where could these invalid bytes be coming from? It looks like all I'm doing is sending normal text. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your websocket-server.py

You have the line:

```
self.send(message.data, message.is_binary)
```

So it looks like the server thinks it is sending back a binary message but chrome is expecting text.

try:

```
self.send(message.data, message.is_text)
```

Comment: Seems like that's not it. The websockets aren't working either way.

Comment: any news on this?